# How to Auto Scroll with Compositional Collection View?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift5, autoscroll, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

[image]

I use Compositional CollectionView to create collectionview with 2 sections. The first section is Horizontal Section as the picture. 1 Group has 3 items ( 3 cells). I want to make auto-scroll for this.
Please, Anyone help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar UI to yours, It's an infinite auto-scrolling collection view using compositional layout. You could check [My Demo Project](https://github.com/rachelpeichen/Infinite_Auto_Scrolling_CollectionView_CompositionalLayout) for reference.

When you use Compositional Layout to set up collection view, `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_:)` won't be fired. So we need to use

```
layout.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = {
  visibleItems, point, environment in
  // Config auto scroll here 
}
```

And remember to invalidate timer when user tap the collection view cell. Please see detailed code in the above link.

Hope this help :)